# dotnet-gitversion.exe /updateAssemblyinfo $destFileName /ensureassemblyinfo in parallel

Tags: .net, powershell, gitversion

My program uses `dotnet-gitversion.exe /updateAssemblyinfo $destFileName /ensureassemblyinfo` to find the version from git tags. It is done as pre-build event in several projects. When I build entire solution, sometimes they run in parallel and try to write to `$destFileName` on the same time and fail.

That is invoked from a powershell script and I tried to lock the file and somehow pass the filestream to dotnet-gitversion but it didn't work since dotnet-gitversion accepts filepath instead of the stream.

Whoud you hint how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

depending on the actual solution this answer might differ, but if understand you correctly you have 2 tasks you have no control over meaning you can't do them in a serial fashion via some kind of dependsOn or anything?

If that's the case, for a quick fix i would just chuck on a lockfile if possible and check if some other process uses it. you can even use the lockfile to add some info on what task is currently locking it if you want:

```
$LockFile = "$destfilename.lock"
#wait for lock to not be there anymore
while(Test-path $lockfile)
{
  #Waiting for lock to dissapear
  Write-host "Waiting for " + (get-content $lockfile) + " to finish.."
  start-sleep -seconds 10
}
#just to make sure system is updated on start of lockfile
start-sleep -Milliseconds 300

#create lockfile
New-Item -itemtype File -path $lockfile -value $CurrentBuildTaskName -force

#Do your thing here

Remove-item -path $lockfile -force
```

for the long haul however, i would try to have some case where you don't do those steps at all when building the 'individual steps' as a part of the main build, but rather have them as a part of the main build. this also saves time as you dont have to essentially the same task 2-3 times

Comment: Thanks for the response, I get what you mean. Looks like there is a problem there. When two processes run on the same time they both will pass while cycle check, create the lock, to thing and remove it....

Comment: @Ashot there might be a race condition if both start at exactly the same time. you might want to add a `start-sleep -Milliseconds (get-random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 300)` to induce some randomness to their start if they happen to run at the same time. you could even concider to upping the random to 1000 if you want.. what you also can do is to check if the `dotnet-gitversion.exe` is currently running instead of using a lockfile